# Edit the DLL code. to enable a function in the game using ESC

Tags: c

*I have a code here and I would like to put a key to enable and disable WSAD*

The function is going straight and because of that it is not possible to write in the game. I would like to use an ESC key to activate and deactivate

**HELP! PLEASE??**

```
    #include <windows.h>

HMODULE origLibrary;
WNDPROC wndProc;

typedef void (*_PushLetter) (int Letter);
_PushLetter PushLetter;

bool isOnline() {
    return (*(DWORD*) 0x79CF28) == 8;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK HookedMessageDispatcher(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (!isOnline()) {
        return CallWindowProc(wndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            switch (wParam) {
                case 0x57:
                {
                    wParam = VK_UP;
                    break;
                }
                case 0x53:
                {
                    wParam = VK_DOWN;
                    break;
                }
                case 0x41:
                {
                    wParam = VK_LEFT;
                    break;
                }
                case 0x44:
                {
                    wParam = VK_RIGHT;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return CallWindowProc(wndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        default:
        {
            return CallWindowProc(wndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

HWND WINAPI HookedCreateWindowEx(DWORD dwExStyle, LPCTSTR lpClassName, LPCTSTR lpWindowName, DWORD dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, HWND hWndParent, HMENU hMenu, HINSTANCE hInstance, LPVOID lpParam) {
    HWND m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
    wndProc = (WNDPROC) GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR) HookedMessageDispatcher);

    return m_hWnd;
}

/*_cdecl */void _stdcall HookedPushLetter(int Letter) {
    if (!isOnline()) {
        PushLetter(Letter);
        return;
    }

    if (Letter == 'A' || Letter == 'a') {
        return;
    }

    if (Letter == 'W' || Letter == 'w') {
        return;
    }

    if (Letter == 'S' || Letter == 's') {
        return;
    }

    if (Letter == 'D' || Letter == 'd') {
        return;
    }

    PushLetter(Letter);
}

void HookCall(DWORD dwCallAddress, DWORD dwNewAddress) {
    DWORD dwOldProtect, dwNewProtect, dwNewCall;
    BYTE call[4];

    dwNewCall = dwNewAddress - dwCallAddress - 5;
    *(DWORD*) call = dwNewCall;

    VirtualProtect((LPVOID) (dwCallAddress + 1), 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, &dwOldProtect);
    dwCallAddress += 1;
    *(DWORD*) dwCallAddress = *(DWORD*) & call;
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID) (dwCallAddress), 5, dwOldProtect, &dwNewProtect);
}

static int InitMain() {
    char systemDirectory[MAX_PATH];
    GetSystemDirectory(systemDirectory, MAX_PATH);
    lstrcat(systemDirectory, "\\ddraw.dll");
    origLibrary = LoadLibrary(systemDirectory);

    if (!origLibrary) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    PushLetter = (_PushLetter) 0x458200;
    HookCall(0x4CFB8A, (DWORD) & HookedPushLetter);

    DWORD dwOldProtect, dwNewProtect, funcAddress, origAddress;
    funcAddress = (DWORD) & HookedCreateWindowEx;
    origAddress = (DWORD) ((int*) 0x5B8574);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID) origAddress, 4, PAGE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect);
    memcpy((LPVOID) origAddress, &funcAddress, 4);
    VirtualProtect((LPVOID) origAddress, 4, dwOldProtect, &dwNewProtect);

    return 1;
}

extern "C" {

    __declspec (dllexport) HRESULT WINAPI DirectDrawCreate(void* lpGUID, void* lplp, void* pUnkOuter) {
        FARPROC proc = GetProcAddress(origLibrary, "DirectDrawCreate");
        if (!proc)
            return E_INVALIDARG;

        return ((HRESULT(WINAPI *)(void*, void*, void*))(DWORD) (proc))(lpGUID, lplp, pUnkOuter);
    }

    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
        switch (dwReason) {
            case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
                return InitMain();
            case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
                break;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

> I'll be waiting, thanks in advance

I'm not getting through, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

someone? I believe that for those who understand the subject know how to solve